# App crashes when I submit score to leaderboard android

Tags: java, android

I have an app that I have published and integrated android leaderboard, but when I play the game with another user(user not added as tester in the playstore dashboard)  the app is crashing when I try to submit the score.
The app is already published and as I know it should work!?! Can someone tell me what can the problem be?

Here is my code:

```
private void submitScore(final int points) {
        if (getApiClient().isConnected()) {
            Log.d("--", "submiting score " + points);
            PendingResult<Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult> result = Games.Leaderboards
                    .loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore(getApiClient(),
                            getString(R.string.poeni_tabela),
                            LeaderboardVariant.TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME,
                            LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC);
            result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(
                        Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult loadPlayerScoreResult) {
                    Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(getApiClient(),
                            getString(R.string.poeni_tabela),
                            loadPlayerScoreResult.getScore().getRawScore()
                                    + points);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

And here is the log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.myapp.QuizActivity$9.onResult(QuizActivity.java:611)
at com.myapp.QuizActivity$9.onResult(QuizActivity.java:1)
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.BaseImplementation$CallbackHandler.deliverResultCallback(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.BaseImplementation$CallbackHandler.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5196)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The line `com.myapp.QuizActivity$9.onResult(QuizActivity.java:611)` is this code:

```
Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(getApiClient(),
                                getString(R.string.poeni_tabela),
                                loadPlayerScoreResult.getScore().getRawScore()
                                        + points);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I've found the answer to my question thanks to @Jens. Seems like `loadPlayerScoreResult.getScore().getRawScore()` is `null`. This I suppose is because the player haven't submited any score yet so in that case you just add the initial score, and next time if its not `null` - and it should not be, you can sum old points with the new ones.

here is the code that im using now in the `submitScore` method above:

```
if (loadPlayerScoreResult.getScore() != null) {
                        Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(getApiClient(),
                                getString(R.string.poeni_tabela),
                                loadPlayerScoreResult.getScore().getRawScore()
                                        + points);
                    } else {
                        Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(getApiClient(),
                                getString(R.string.poeni_tabela), points);
                    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are more possibilities:

```
Games.Leaderboards is null
loadPlayerScoreResult is null
loadPlayerScoreResult.getScore() is null
loadPlayerScoreResult.getScore().getRawScore() is null
```

Use a debugger to find out what is happend.

Comment: seems that `loadPlayerScoreResult.getScore().getRawScore()` is null any idea how can i get the score without using `getRawScore()`, my score is like 1234567 without decimal spaces or anything else

Comment: @DarkoPetkovski No sorry

Comment: Thanks, you've been very helpful, I've managed to find the answer to my question!